# Disable delete namespace - Kubernetes

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes, kubectl

I created a namespace called `qc` for qc environment.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.namespace.name | quote }}
```

`kubectl create -f namespace.yaml`

But I can delete this namespace anytime by running `kubectl delete namespace qc`.

How can I disable to delete user created namespaces?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want disable deletion of Namespaces for your kubernetes-admin user, although it could be possible. If there are other people or services interacting with your cluster, you need to define Users and/or Service Accounts for them and bind Cluster Roles to them, whitelisting their permissions. Have a look at [Users in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#users-in-kubernetes) and [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/) in the official Kubernetes Documentation.

Comment: Do you know if there is a nice solution to intentionally prevent admins delete namespaces...?

Comment: Yes, use the admin-level account only to initially configure the cluster and accounts with lower permissions.
Then use the restricted accounts for day-to-day work. If you find the restricted account doesn't have enough permissions, use the admin account to grant it the necessary permissions